# dotnet.exe command for .NET and .NET Core

Tags: .net, .net-core

I have installed ".NET Framework" on my computer. I have also installed ".NET Core Framework".

Which framework is used, when I run the `dotnet.exe` command? I was thinking there will be 2 `dotnet.exe` commands, but there is only one.

Answer (score 3):

The `dotnet.exe` tool belongs to [.Net Core CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/?tabs=netcore2x) (Command Line Interface), there really isn't an equivalent in the older .Net Framework.

You can have multiple `dotnet.exe` files on your system, but they would all be .Net Core, as it allows side-by-side installations of multiple versions.  It will default to the newest version (including pre-release versions), unless you designate which one to use via a [`global.json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/global-json) file.

Comment: To add to that, .NET Framework is the original implementation that runs on Windows. It's installed system-wide, and .NET assemblies use the existing Windows executable format, so when you run a .NET `.exe` the OS is responsible for calling the .NET Framework's runtime - there's no need for any special command like `dotnet`. Other things that the `dotnet` command does in .NET Core are done by other commands for .NET Framework, such as `msbuild` for building projects.